# Misunderstanding the process of JWT authentication

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I create project using React + Redux + Apollo Client + Graphql

When we need to log in in our app we need to use token (saved in localStorage for example) which is put in the headers parameter like in the code below:

```
const client = new ApolloClient ({
 uri: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
 headers: {
  authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
 }, 
});
```

After request server verifies token and becomes aware who is the user.

My question: from where do we need to get token and put it to the headers parameter for log on (sign up) process? A new customer comes to our log on page, he has no token (in localStorage or somewhere else) at the beginning but server requires it in the requests. And if we remove headers parameter from our client, the log on process will proceed but server won't understand who is the current user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header

Comment: @Agney, no, docs say you need to put headers but don't include my situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision:

you need to check for token in localStorage and update the request if token exists

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
  request (operation) {
    const headers = {};
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    operation.setContext({ headers });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically the server would be the one issuing the JWT token, and this would happen during user login or maybe during account creation.  For these particular calls, you should *not* be expecting the JWT in the header.  Instead, the user would be passing credentials, such as username and password.  For most other calls, it is appropriate to pass the JWT in the header of the request.

Keep in mind that the main purpose of the JWT is free the user from having to provide personal credentials during most requests.  Instead, the user can just present a JWT, much as one would present a passport, to get access to your web services.

In response to your comments below, I would suggest that you keep the signup/registration process separate from the user-only area of your application.  Here is a typical workflow:

- Prospective user visits your site, and creates an account, by choosing a username and password, and possibly by providing certain other personal information
- Your application creates an account, and then sends an email verification link to the user's email address.  The server lands the user on a page which mentions all of this
- The user opens the email, which contains a verification link, which when clicked will activate the account.  Your application returns a web page which then asks the user to login.
- Finally, the user logs in from the normal login page.

Note carefully here, that JWT were *not* at all involved in the signup process, nor do they need to be.  The user JWT only needs to come into existence after the user actually logs in for the first time.

Comment: so I need to sent only credentials to the server during account creation? But in that situation how server understand who is current user?

Comment: @rgdzv If the account doesn't yet exist, then server won't know who the user is.

Comment: my situation is a little more complicated. After registration process I need to redirect user to the other page. On that page I need to show first and second name of the user (which I need to get from the log on process but it provides only token). Also that page is about edit information of user. If the server doesn't understand who is current user, it will not ba able to update information about current user

Comment: Check the updated answer.  You are asking about (and seem to have doubts on) multiple things, not just JWT.

Comment: thanks for answer. I understood that I need to avoid my situation. Is it even possible to redirect user after registration on the page you want and consider him as current user?

Comment: Yes, you may do a login with the credentials chosen.  But, typically you would not do this, because you would want to verify the user's email and/or identity before you activate his account.